# Using a variable from one Javascript file in another returns undefined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use a variable from one Javascript file in another, but in the other file I am getting a console error of 'undefined'.

The data is retrieved from an API call which is then assigned to a variable on an event click. The console displays the variable fine on the first page, but when I click to the next page to try to display the variable in the 2nd JS file and use it, it is undefined.

I have tried making the variable global within the function by doing the following:

```
        UICtrl.createTrackDetail(track.danceability);
        var danceabilityData = track.danceability; //create a global variable?
        console.log(danceabilityData)
```

I am also able to use the variable in another function in the same file to display the data on the first HTML page.

I am then trying to use it in the second JS file by using console.log to test this, but this returns undefined.

```
import danceabilityData from './app';
console.log(danceabilityData);
```

I have also tried to export and import the variable but I get the error 'Cannot use import statement outside a module' on the second HTML page. Changing the type of the HTML page to module also breaks my javascript canvas and nothing loads.

Comment: API calls are asynchronous. Are you trying to use the variable outside the callback function?

Comment: How it breaks the javascript canvas?

Comment: Are these different `.js` files loaded by the same HTML, or are they different HTML pages? When you load a new HTML page, all JavaScript state is reset. You can use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` to preserve variables.

Comment: @Barmar they are different .js files loaded by two different HTML pages. That must be why they are being reset. I will look into localStorage and sessionStorage. Thanks!